# Solving non linear equations in R using BB package

Tags: r

I was trying to solve a set of non linear equations but stuck.

```
0<x1<1 ; x2>0 ; x3>0

library(BB) 

f <- function(x) { 
  x1 <- x[1] 
  x2 <- x[2]
  x3 <- x[3] 

  F <- rep(NA, 3) 

  F[1] <- 1-x1^(log(1+1/(x3)^x2))-0.64

  F[2] <- x1^(log(1+1/(x3)^x2))-x1^(log(1+(2/x3)^x2))-0.17

  F[3] <- x1^(log(1+(2/x3)^x2))-x1^(log(1+(3/x3)^x2))-0.10

  return(F) 
} 

p0 <- c(0.5,2,1) 

dfsane(par=p0, fn=f,control=list(maxit=30000))
```

It stuck with an error on first iteration only

> "Failure: Error in function evaluation"

Can anyone help how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this sort of error, you might print out the value of `x` that is being processed at each function iteration to identify the argument that is causing your function to misbehave.

When I did so, I found that the following input data is problematic:

```
x <- c(-1.199934, -2.745093,  3.648077)
f(x)
# [1] NaN NaN NaN
```

You should update your function so it doesn't return `NaN` for out-of-bounds data (or move to a solver that accepts constraints on the function arguments).

Comment: @ Josliber, Yes you are true. actually i have constraints on the function arguments as i mentioned in the starting as 0<x1<1 ; x2>0 ; x3>0. Can any one help how to tacle such situation.

Comment: @BilalPara The nloptr package provides constrained non-linear optimization; you might check out if that works in your case.

Comment: @ Josliber,I am bit confused how to use optimization method to get solution of the nonlinear equations there.